# How to pass string with ' ' (timestamp) in prepared statement?

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error, insert-update, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to execute the following query

```
INSERT INTO hotspot(timestamp) VALUES 
(timestamp with time zone '2012-10-25 14:00:00 +05:00' at time zone 'EET');
```

and i want to pass the timestamp as a variable.

My timestamp column is type of timestamp with time zone.

Do you have any idea how this can be done?

When i do... (Java, Postgresql)

```
    String stm= "INSERT INTO hotspot(timestamp) VALUES(timestamp with time zone ? at time zone 'EET')";
    pst = con.prepareStatement(stm);
    pst.setString(1, "2012-08-24 14:00:00 +05:00");
    pst.executeUpdate();
```

I get a  syntax error at or near "$1"

Is there anyway i can overcome this error??
Thank you in advance!!

***Update:*** I tried to use the setTimestamp by the following way...

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:00"));
String stm= "INSERT INTO hotspot(timestamp) VALUES(?)";
pst = con.prepareStatement(stm);
pst.setTimestamp(1,Timestamp.valueOf("2012-01-05 14:00:00"), c );
pst.executeUpdate();
```

I suppose that the correct value in the DB should be (regarding that my local time zone is EET (+02))

2012-01-05 11:00:00 +02

but using pgadmin i check the value and i get

2012-01-05 14:00:00 +02

Any suggestions?

Comment: timestamp is a column of hotspot table?  Isn't timestamp a reserved word?

Comment: @FedericoCristina Yes timestamp is a column in table hotspot. I dont think that timestamp is a reserved word

Comment: Well, timestamp is a data type, and it is *at least* a bad habit (IMnsvHO)to give your column names the names of the datatype. Would you name your child "child" ?

Comment: @Michelangelo you are right about timestamp column. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using the **setTimestamp()** method instead of **setString()** method.  Check [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/DemoPreparedStatementSetTimestamp.htm) in order to understand how to use *PreparedStatement*.

Edit: As I explained in the comment, check the [API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp,%20java.util.Calendar%29) for setTimestamp() with three parameters:

> Sets the designated parameter to the given java.sql.Timestamp value,
>   using the given Calendar object. The driver uses the Calendar object
>   to construct an SQL TIMESTAMP value, which the driver then sends to
>   the database. With a Calendar object, the driver can calculate the
>   timestamp taking into account a custom timezone. If no Calendar object
>   is specified, the driver uses the default timezone, which is that of
>   the virtual machine running the application.

Comment: When i used setTimestamp() i couldnt make the DB set a time zone different than the default one that is why i chose the afore mentioned way

Comment: Then consider using the [more complete option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp,%20java.util.Calendar%29) of setTimeStamp(), the one with three parameters.  With a _Calendar_ object, the driver can calculate the timestamp taking into account a custom timezone.

Comment: @MichelangeloVandilakis Rather than messing with `AT TIME ZONE`, consider setting `TimeZone` in the connection correctly for your location, and storing `timestamp with time zone` values instead of the quirky-and-hard-to-get-right `timestamp without time zone` (unqualified `timestamp`).

Comment: @CraigRinger I forgot to mention that timestamp column in my DB is type of timestamp with time zone!

Comment: @FedericoCristina According to my update (if it is correct ) it doesnt work like mentioned above

Answer (score 4):

Federico Cristina is quite right that `setTimestamp` is the correct way to do this.

The reason for the syntax error is that you can't specify the type with a leading type-specifier when passing a parameter. The `INTEGER '4'` style is only valid for *literals*, not parameters.

Your code will be `PREPARE`d then `EXECUTE`d at the protocol level. Here's what happens if I `PREPARE` it:

```
regress=> PREPARE blah(timestamptz) AS INSERT INTO hotspot(timestamp) VALUES(timestamp with time zone $1 at time zone 'EET');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: ...otspot(timestamp) VALUES(timestamp with time zone $1 at time...
```

Since the data type is specified in the query parameter you can omit it, writing instead:

```
String stm= "INSERT INTO hotspot(\"timestamp\") VALUES(? at time zone 'EET')";
```

Note that I've double-quoted `"timestamp"` as well, because it's a reserved word. It'll work without quotes in some contexts but not others. Choosing a data type name or reserved word as a column name is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I tried to test the above correction but i got this error
ERROR: function pg_catalog.timezone(unknown, character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @MichelangeloVandilakis ... and how did you call it? Did you use setTimestamp to set the parameter? Consider editing your question and appending the updated code you tried.

Comment: @MichelangeloVandilakis Looking at the update, you don't seem to use `tz` anywhere. How are you determining the value in the DB? Java/JDBC query and if so, which one? `psql`?

Comment: I use pgadmin and i check the value. I didnt know where to use the tz variable in order to adjust the time zone :/

Comment: I also changed the way i initialize the calendar using the preferable time zone